# Confusion with independent R.V

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

Could someone help me clear up some confusion I have over independence/dependence of R.V :

---

Question 1)
Say we have two random variables $X$ and $Y,$ with $Y$ dependent on $X$

$X$ distributed $\operatorname{Uniform}(0,1).$

$Y$ distributed
$$
F_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 0, & y<0 \\ 1, & y>1 \\ y, & y\in [0,1] \end{cases}
$$
i.e it is $\operatorname{Uniform}(0,1),$ however let $Y=\frac{1}{2}$ if $X\in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ so $Y$ depends on $X.$

Then am I right in saying Y is still distributed $\operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$ since its C.D.F is unchanged?

---

Question 2)

Say $X$ and $Y$ are distributed as Bernouli R.V i.e they are $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p.$

However it is also the case that if $X=1$ then $Y=0$ and if $Y=0$ then $X=1$ so they are dependent on each-other.

Then how would one calculate $P(X=1,Y=0)$ since there is no "conditioned on" does this mean (in a real world sense) we are running both experiments simultaneously and so neither has a dependence on the other?

Comment: 1) If I understand you, $\mathbb P(Y=\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}$, and thus $Y$ is not uniformly distributed.

Comment: Can you justify this statement using expressions with X in it?

Comment: $P(Y=1/2)=P(Y=1/2|X \in (0,1/2))P(X \in (0,1/2)) + P(Y=1/2|X \in (1/2,1))P(X \in (1/2,1)) = 1/2 + 0$ hm so your right there, but if we write $F_{Y}(y)$ without knowing anything about X it is uniform. Im really confusing myself now

Comment: **7 minutes**. $ $

Comment: What do you mean did?

Comment: That accepting an answer after such a short time span "closes the case", so to speak, hence reduces drastically the number of potential answerers, hence of potential answers, and in particular of possible **better** answers. Additionally this raises the question of whether the OP (you) fully analyzed the answer and fully understood it. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: @Did ah okay. Im quite new to this sight and oversaw this. I did read the answer and take it in. I guess i closed the case so to speak because I realised my question was rather trivial and the response clarifies things. I will take this into account in the future though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distribution of $X$ implies that $\Pr(X<1/2) = 1/2,$ so $\Pr(Y=1/2) \ge 1/2,$ and thus the c.d.f. of $Y$ is *not* what you reported it to be; $Y$ is not uniformly distributed.

In your case of Bernoulli distributions, you say $\Pr(X=1) = \Pr(Y=1) = p$ and $\Pr(X=0) = \Pr(Y=0) = 1-p.$ And you also say $X=0$ if, but only if, $Y=1.$ That implies
$$
1-p = \Pr(X=0) = \Pr(Y=1) = p.
$$
Thus $1-p=p,$ so $p=1/2.$

You have $\Pr(X=1\ \&\ Y=0) = 1/2$ and $\Pr(X=0\ \&\ Y=1) = 1/2.$

You can also say $\Pr(X=1\ \&\ Y=0) = \Pr(X=1)\cdot\Pr(Y=0\mid X=1) = \dfrac 1 2 \cdot 1.$